# http_request succeeds but Groovy code gets 401

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I was using the [HTTP Request Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) to make an API call to my Bitbucket server.

The following call returns the desired result:

```
def my-url = "http://my-username:my-password@my-bitbucket-server.com:7990/rest/api/1.0/my-project/pull-request-10"
def response = http_request my-url
```

However, I had an issue with the HTTP Request Plugin, because it prints my password in plain text in the logs.

Therefore, I tried doing the same call from a groovy script:

```
def response = new URL(my-url).getText()
```

But for this I am getting a `401` server response.

Any idea why this time, the call fails?

Comment: First of all, I don't see how the first snippet gave you any result at all, since `my-url` is not, on its own, a valid identifier.

Comment: It's not, because I changed its name before posting it here.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to apply Basic auth using almost plain Java. You have to generate your auth key and attach it to the request headers. Try:

```
String addr = 'my-bitbucket-server.com:7990/rest/api/1.0/my-project/pull-request-10'
String authString = 'my-username:my-password'.getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
def conn = addr.toURL().openConnection()
conn.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "Basic ${authString}" )
def feed = new XmlSlurper().parseText( conn.content.text )
```

Hope this would help!

Comment: I have been scouring SO and google for before coming across this CONSICE, yet COMPREHENSIVE answer. If  I had more upvotes I would give them to you.